# laravel update column value recursive

Tags: php, recursion, laravel-4

for example i have the following table:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
| ID | message     | status  | parent_id |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
|1   | hello world | pending | 0         |
|2   | test nested | pending | 1         |
|3   | 3rd comment | pending | 2         |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

When I want to update status of `ID #3` to `approved`, it should also update status of its parent, which is `ID #2`, then `ID #2` should also update its parent which is `ID #1`.

is there an easy way of doing this in Laravel? currently I use recursive function. just curious if there is an easy way.

Comment: isn't this more of a database specific problem rather than PHP ?

Comment: I am not sure. in my point of view, it could be solve using both programing PHP or database. but I want to know if there is an easy way of doing this in laravel, using `Eloquent` or `Query Builder`